# Combine arrays in the beginning of a for-loop (Bash)

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
a=( 1 2 3 )
b=( 4 5 6 )
for num in ( ${a[@]} ${b[@]} ) # or: for num in ${( ${a[@]} ${b[@]} )[@]}
do
    echo "$num"
done
# Outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I know you can combine them before and then loop through them, but is it possible in only one line?

Current solution:

```
a=( 1 2 3 )
b=( 4 5 6 )
c=( ${a[@]} ${b[@]} )
for num in ${c[@]}
do
    echo "$num"
done
# Outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Why not? have you tried it and got an error?

Comment: Yes i have, try to test the first code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify both arrays.

```
for num in "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}"
 ...
```